# jQuery hide and show collapse multiple divs

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I need to be able to hide and show divs on a page.

I need one active by default then when I click on other links to show another div, I need the active div to hide, and so on. So only one div is open at one given time.

I have put a demo together to show what I require, I have got it working so to speak, but I need it to collapse/hide the active div once another link is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/QFfzs/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a class to the divs you're trying to hide, then hide the all divs before toggling like this:

```
//adding '.hideMe' to the divs to be toggled
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideDetailsDiv').hide();
    $('a#hideDetailsButton').click(function() {
        if (!$('#hideDetailsDiv').is(':visible')) {
            $('.hideMe').hide(400);
        }
        $('#hideDetailsDiv').toggle(400);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFfzs/4/

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFfzs/5/ (done with less code)

Comment: is it possible to get a link back to the default box as well similar to the show ... links??

Comment: @Paul - the easiest way of doing this would be to add link to that default box and hide it at beginning. Then after another box is showing this link will become visible

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$('.primaryButton2').click(function(){
   $('.hideDetailsDiv').hide();//hide all divs, add to them class .hideDetailsDiv
   $(this).nextAll('.hideDetailsDiv:first').show(400);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete bin for above issue. you can check demo link....

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp84

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <a href="#">
    Show Default
  </a>
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Default Div Box is already Active..!
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    Show Box1
  </a>
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Showing Div Box 1..!
    </p>
  </div>

  <a href="#">
    Show Box2
  </a>
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Showing Div Box 2..!
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    Show Box3
  </a>
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Showing Div Box 3..!
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    Show Box4
  </a>
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      Showing Div Box 4..!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
  border:1px solid #334478;
  width:400px;
  height:50px;
  background:#f7a8a5;
  margin-top:3px;
  /* Default All Divs Are Hidden*/
  display:none;
}
#panel a{
  display:block;
  font-size:13px;
}
.box p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    //Show Default First div is Active
    $("#panel .box:first").show();
    $("#panel a").click(function() {
        $("#panel .box").hide(400);
        $(this).next(".box").show("slow");
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp84